# Binding to readonly property in generic.xaml for customControl (Button)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I'm doing a CustomControl (button) using generic.xaml and dependency properties.

Here is my generic.xaml code :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FlatButton}">
     <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:FlatButton}">
                <Grid MinHeight="50" MaxHeight="50" MinWidth="200" MaxWidth="200">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>     

                    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="{TemplateBinding BackgroundDarker}">

                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My customControl class :

```
Public Shared Shadows BackgroundProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Background", GetType(SolidColorBrush), GetType(FlatButton))
Public Overloads Property Background As SolidColorBrush
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(BackgroundProperty), SolidColorBrush)
    End Get
    Set(value As SolidColorBrush)
        SetValue(BackgroundProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared BackgroundDarkerProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundDarker", GetType(SolidColorBrush), GetType(FlatButton))
Public ReadOnly Property BackgroundDarker As SolidColorBrush
    Get
        Return Background.Darker
    End Get
End Property
```

And finally how I use my control in a UserControl :

```
<Grid>
    <local:FlatButton Background="Red" />
</Grid>
```

When I put "Red" in the xaml of my FlatButton, the right part is well colored in Red (in VS and in runtime), but what I want is that the left part colores itself automatically with Darker red (it's an extension which works). But it seems not to be colored. I've no binding error in output.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks all.

**-----EDIT-----** :

Ok, to do that I made a converter which convert the "Background" value to a darker color.
I templateBinded the background of the left grid to "Background" with an instance of my converter.

Comment: It won't work that way, because there is no mechanism that tells the `BackgroundDarker` binding that the property has changed. I'd suggest to use a regular binding with a converter instead.

Comment: You should either write an answer or delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a converter will work, this functionality belongs inside the `FlatButton` control code. Use the Background's `PropertyChangedCallback` to update BackgroundDarker.

[image] [image] [image]

```
public class FlatButton : Button
{
    // Background
    public static new DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Background", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(FlatButton), new PropertyMetadata(OnBackgroundChanged));
    public new SolidColorBrush Background { get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(BackgroundProperty); } set { SetValue(BackgroundProperty, value); } }

    // BackgroundDarker
    public static DependencyProperty BackgroundDarkerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundDarker", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(FlatButton));
    public SolidColorBrush BackgroundDarker { get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(BackgroundDarkerProperty); } private set { SetValue(BackgroundDarkerProperty, value); } }

    private static void OnBackgroundChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // update BackgroundDarker
        var btn = (FlatButton)d;
        btn.BackgroundDarker = btn.Background.Darker();
    }

    static FlatButton()
    {
        // lookless control, get default style from generic.xaml
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FlatButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(FlatButton)));
    }
}

public static class SolidColorBrushExtension
{
    public static SolidColorBrush Darker(this SolidColorBrush brush)
    {
        const double perc = 0.6;
        return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)(brush.Color.R * perc), (byte)(brush.Color.G * perc), (byte)(brush.Color.B * perc)));
    }
}
```